# Origins of the most popular file serving pattern in web

Tags: design-patterns

Most modern file upload/sharing services, apart from having lots of ads and constantly offering you to buy a subscription, also share the same design pattern: when you are ready to download a file they typically write something like "Your download should start automatically in 5 seconds. Click *here* to download manually."

What rationale stands behind this behavior? Where did it come from? Why don't they just send a redirect or open a temporary link in another window (via `target="_blank"`)? TIA

Comment: it is not only upload/sharing services, but almost all sites where you can download files. including SourceForge for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's because it's become what people expect. Often a direct link to a file will leave the user with a blank window while their file downloads (depending on the browser, I haven't checked but I'm pretty sure this behaviour was common with browsers 5 years ago), so avoiding this is good. I'd wager that most internet users would be confused if they clicked a download link and were presented with a blank page (and a dialog somewhere, possible hidden, downloading the file). Since this has become commonplace, it's now what users expect, so doing it another way would make it more confusing for most users, even if it does make more sense!

Comment: Also, on ad-supported sites, this pattern allows you to generate one more page impression.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation indeed.

Answer (score 4):

They probably sell premium ads on those pages, because most people will be looking at the ads while they wait for their download to finish. Guaranteed viewage is gold.